# Graphviz - multiple links for each section of the record

Tags: svg, graphviz

I know that this can be done with the HTML label instead of the record label, but I want to see if this is possible with the record shape for its simplicity for the rest of the graph.

I have this for example:

`struct1 [label="{<f0> link1|{<f1> link 2 |<f2> link 3}}", URL="[https://sampleurl.com]"];`

All three, sections of the record go to the same link. How do I assign each of them a separate link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "shapes" documentation (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/doc/info/shapes.html - a little hard to find)  creates a port named **xyz**:

```
digraph structs {
    node [shape=record];
    struct1 [label="<f0> left|<f1> mid&#92; dle|<f2> right"];
    struct2 [label="<f0> one|<f1> two"];
    struct3 [label="hello&#92;nworld |{ b |{c|<here> d|e}| f}| g | h"];
    struct1:f1 -> struct2:f0;
    struct1:f2 -> struct3:here;
}
```

Comment: But in this format, how would you add distinct links for each of the sections as in: a link for  "left", another link for "mid&#92", and another for "right".

I even tried something like: 
`struct1:f1 [URL="[https://google.com]"];
  struct1:f2 [URL="[https://bing.com]"];
  struct1:f0 [URL="[https://sampleurl.com]"];`

and here, all 3 end up routing to the last url: https://sampleurl.com

Comment: Sorry, your question was clear, but I mis-read.  The syntax just does not seem to allow what you want.  The record shape is still a single node, so a single URL attribute.  Note that you could have 3 edges coming off the record, each with a different URL.  Otherwise html labels.